# std::is_constructible in a list

Tags: c++, c++14

I want to find the type from a list I can construct with a template parameter. In this example:

```
using my_type = typename get_constructible<char *, int, std::string>::type;
```

`my_type` must be `std::string` because in the list `std::string` is the first that can be constructed with a `char *`.

I tried this:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template<typename T, typename... Rest>
struct get_constructible
{
  using type = void;
};

template<typename T, typename First, typename... Rest>
struct get_constructible<T, First, Rest...>
{
  using type = typename std::conditional<
    std::is_constructible<First, T>::value,
    First,
    get_constructible<T, Rest...>::type
  >::type;
};

int main(void)
{
  using my_type = get_constructible<char *, int, std::string>::type;
  my_type s("Hi!");
}
```

I do not understand where my logic fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your logic looks fine, but you're missing a `typename` on the dependent name `get_constructible<T, Rest...>::type`:

```
using type = typename std::conditional<
  std::is_constructible<First, T>::value,
  First,
  typename get_constructible<T, Rest...>::type
//^^^^^^^^
>::type;
```

Comment: clang error: "error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type; **did you forget 'typename'?**"

Comment: That's why I compile with both gcc and clang when I don't quickly understand an error. One of them could hold my hand, like in this example.

Comment: @bolov I compile under vsc++ and the error messages are all but helpful… I am under ms windows and I know nothing about this OS (I don't know how to install clang). Aside from that, I am tired of those things in c++: I cannot understand the `typename` rules.

Comment: @Boiethios Have a read of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords). Essentially, if the type depends on a template parameter, then you need `typename`.

Comment: @Boiethios when you have a MCVE like this one a convenient solution is to try it in an online compiler e.g. http://gcc.godbolt.org/ (don't know why I can't create a link with your code, anyway basically paste your code and select the latest gcc or clang from the compiler dropdown)

Comment: @bolov I think the UI changed, sharing links is now the second toolbar icon from the right on the source code pane.

Comment: @bolov Thanks, the site is in my favorites now ;) I compiled under clang++ at school before, and I prefer by far its messages.